# Drawio-desktop disable autosave?

Tags: drawing

Is there a way to disable `autosave` in the configuration? similar to other configuration parameters from the Menu, `Extras` > `Configuration...` ?
I tried following but didn't worked out:

```
{ "autosave": 0 }
```

The reason behind it is, I'm quite often open diagrams on a shared drive, and if I leave the `Extras` > `Autosave` option on, then any accidental change on the diagram gets saved to the shared drive. My hope is with the option as configuration parameter, each time I open a diagram by default it will be set to `autosave=false`.

Answer (score 11):

You can enable/disable it by clicking Extras -> Autosave as shown on the image below.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: thanks, yes, as mentioned in my question, i'm aware. however if i close drawio with autosave on, then drawio starts also with autosave on. therefore if it can be set in config my hope was that on each start of drawio it would disable it automatically.

Comment: Can you set it off permanently, so auto-save would stay disabled even after re-launching the app?